# Different array sizes and using SUMXMY2 function

Tags: excel, sum, excel-2007, array-difference

I'm trying to use the SUMXMY2 function in excel to return the sum of squares of differences of corresponding values in two arrays. Problem is that I want my second array to be a single constant. Excel returns the #N/A error if array_x and array_y have a different amount of values. If array_x has 8 values, then array_y must have 8 values.

The equation I'm trying to apply is this:

```
X = {(1/7)*SUM[(Y_i - Y_avg)]^2}^(1/2)
```

where Y_i = the individual values of L1 through L8 on the table below, and
      Y_avg = the average of values L1 through L8

```
L1    L2    L3    L4    L5    L6    L7    L8    SUM    AVERAGE
42.5  37.0  40.0  44.9  40.1  37.6  40.3  42.6  324.9  40.6
```

I'd rather not make a table that repeats Y_avg 8 times (thereby matching the two arrays) because I need the excel sheet to be neat and take up as little space as it can.

Is there a way to get the SUMXMY2 function in excel to return the sum of squares of differences of one array and one constant like I outlined above? Or is there another function or simple workaround i can use?

Comment: The table didn't come out very good.

Comment: You're trying to get the (n-1) Standard deviation, right?? - You could use the `STDEV(L1:L8)` function....

Comment: I used another function that worked out well:

    =SQRT((1/7)*SUMPRODUCT((L1:L8-Lavg)^2))

    Thank you John for editing my question to make the table look nice. I'm gonna check to see if STDEV(L1:L8) would have worked all along.

Comment: Yup. It was the same thing. SQRT((1/7)*SUMPRODUCT((L1:L8-Lavg)^2)) is the same as STDEV(L1:L8). I feel silly.

Comment: Glad you got it working!!